# Having errors with userdefined functions

Tags: matlab

Doing homework and there's a question that's giving me trouble. The questions is:

a)create a function M-file called nmoles that requires two vector inputs—
the mass and molecular weight—and returns the corresponding number
of moles. Because you are providing vector input, it will be necessary
to use the meshgrid function in your calculations.

b) Test your function for the compounds shown in the following table, for
masses from 1 to 10 g:

In my function file, i've got:

```
function [ n ] = nmoles(m, MW)
%% Finds number of moles


m = (1:10); %% mass range
MW = [78.115 46.07 102.3]; %% Values from the table

n=m/MW; %%formula provided by the textbook
```

My main file only has:

```
nmoles(m,MW)
```

I'm getting an error: "Error using / Matrix dimensions must agree"
Also: Error in nmoles (line 10) n=m/MW;

I'm inexperienced with MATLAB and still learning syntax but I assume that my formula is incorrect and i'm using the wrong symbol to divide, though i'm not sure how to correct this. Also, how would i incorporate the meshgrid function into my anwser?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your function should probably look like:

```
function [ n ] = nmoles(m, MW)
% Finds number of moles
[mv,MWv] = meshgrid(m, MW); % extends m and MW to match all combinations.
n = mv./MWv; %formula provided by the textbook
end
```

And then your main script should be:

```
m = 1:10; % mass range
MW = [78.115 46.07 102.3]; % Values from the table
nmoles(m, MW)
```

You had 3 mistakes:

1. If you get `m` and `MW` as input to the function, your not suppose to define them within it.
2. Because you want the number of moles for each combination of mass and molar weight, you use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html?searchHighlight=meshgrid).
3. When you want to perform an elementwise division or multiplication on 2 arrays, put a `.` before the `/` or `*`. In MATLAB everything is a matrix by default, and so this operations are interpreted as matrix [multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) and [division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) by default. If you want to do a [regular division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) or [multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) you use `.*` and `./`. This is true also for power ([`^`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) and [`.^`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html)).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I always find troubleshooting difficult but i'll be sure to make a note of my mistakes for future reference.

Comment: @PaulL if this answer solved your problem , consider accepting it by clicking the green V on the left of it.